# How to have access to a pre-calculated MD5 of the content in a stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I downloaded the file from a remote server then directly pipe the request stream to the gridfs write stream. Is there a way I we could check the the pre calculated md5 so that i can compare it to the stored md5 so i can avoid duplicates in storing files to mongo databse using mongo grid fs.

## Code snippet

```
  var download = function (url, dest, callback) {

        const fileStorage = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: dest });

        request.get(url)
               .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
               .pipe(fileStorage)
               .on('close', callback);

    };

    final_list.forEach(function (str) {
        var filename = str.split('/').pop();

        console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

        download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
    });
```